# Hovering a paragraph makes list items move to the side

Tags: html, css, position

Whenever I hover over the #email all the social icons move to the left for a portion. Ideas were to use positition: fixed or float. I want to do that the icons stay intact but the #email still hovers.

HERE is the code - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyubq

```
#header ul li {
width:48px;
height:48px;
margin-left:15px;
margin-top: 5px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#000000;
padding:0;
text-align: center;

}
#google{
width:48px;
height:48px;
border-radius: 50%/50%;
background-image:url('images/googleplus.png');
display:block;
}
#facebook{
width:48px;
height:48px;
border-radius: 50%/50%;
background-image:url('http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/themes/bradsknutson/images/facebook-48circle.png');
display:block;
}
#twitter{
width:48px;
height:48px;
border-radius: 50%/50%;
background-image:url('http://www.gmailnotifier.se/img/icon_twitter.png');
display:block;
}
#header ul li#google{
background-color:#d34836;
transition:background-color;
transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#header ul li#google:hover{
background-color:#c23725;
}
#header ul li#facebook{
background-color:#3b5998;
transition:background-color;
transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#header ul li#facebook:hover{
background-color:#2a4887;
}
#header ul li#twitter{
background-color:#2447B2;
transition:background-color;
transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#header ul li#twitter:hover{
background-color:#1F3D99;
}

#email {
float: right;
margin-right: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
}
#email:hover {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your html or put on jsfiddle so that we can try

Comment: Putting an Email address like that on a webpage will be asking for spam, If you can use PHP to send the mail it would be better as you can hide your address

Comment: @Billy Can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: `<?php mail($email_to_send_to, $subject_of_email, $email_body); ?>` In your html file do a link to a contact form and send the form to a php file, for instance mail.php, Then get the form inputs and create vars from them, i.e.  subject and message and then the address you want it sent to

Comment: If you use jquery ui you could have the form pop up as a dialog rather then sending them to another page, might be a bit better looking. Have a look here aswell [Jquery pop up contact form](http://www.formget.com/jquery-popup-form/)

Answer (score 4):

Your font becomes greater . And padding calculates from greater font (bold), not the regular.
I can advise you [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jt1sv2ev/). When you hovering,`text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;` appears instead of `font-weight:bold;`.

Comment: Actually that's nice looking. :D Thanks. But still I want to know the cause and the solution without changing font-weight: bold to be sure the next time.

Answer (score 1):

I think Animus's answer is better but if you want to use font-weight:bold then you have to absolute position it  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqyzs

```
#email{
position:absolute;
right:0;
margin-right: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
}
```